# I am unable to store the check box state when the page is refreshed in local Storage?

Tags: javascript

I am unable to store the check box state. I try to store the state in local storage but after page refresh the tick disappears from the checkbox.

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" onchange = "save();">Tick the check box</input>
</form>
<script>
    function save() {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
        localStorage.setItem('check', checkbox.checked);
    }

    window.onload()=function() {    
        var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('check'));
        document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked = checked;
    }
<script>
```

Comment: `window.onload()=function(){` should be `window.onload =function(){`

Comment: @charlietfl `localStorage.item = true` is converted tu `"true"`.

Comment: @charlietfl @klenium Remember that he's using `JSON.parse()` to turn the string into a Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

With `window.onload()`, you call a function, not declare it. Change

```
window.onload()=function(){
```

to

```
window.onload = function() {
```

And a much better way if you use jQuery:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
<label for="checkbox1">Tick the check box</label>
```

```
$(function()
{
    $("#checkbox1").change(function()
    {
        localStorage.check = this.checked;
    });
    var isChecked = localStorage.check ? localStorage.check == "true" : false;
    $("#checkbox1").prop("checked", isChecked);
});
```

jQuery has a function, called [.ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). You do not need to parse `localStorage.check`, since its value isn't an JSON object. Everything in the `localStorage` are stored as string, `localStorage.check == "true"` will give you a real boolean value. You also need a default value, `false`, if the user haven't clicked on the checkbox. `<input>text</input>` is an invalid syntax. Use `<label>` if you want "clickable" text.

---

Edit: for all checkboxes in a form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="some.php">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
    <label for="checkbox1">Tick the check box</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
    <label for="checkbox2">Tick the check box</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" />
    <label for="checkbox3">Tick the check box</label>
</form>
```

```
$(function()
{
    $("#myForm input[type='checkbox']").change(function()
    {
        localStorage[$(this).attr("id")] = this.checked;
    });
    $("#myForm input[type='checkbox']").each(function()
    {
        var val = localStorage[$(this).attr("id")];
        var isChecked = val !== undefined ? val == "true" : false;
        $(this).prop("checked", isChecked);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and since the code you have written is only for single checkbox and is it possible to write a very few lines of code for multiple checkboxes so that it will be applicable to all check boxes in a form.

Comment: @satish Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two changes:

1. Change `window.onload() =` to `window.onload =`.
2. Remember to call `save()` whenever the checkbox changes value with `.addEventListener("change", save)`.

```js
//Our checkbox
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox1');

//This function saves the checkbox value:
function save() {
    localStorage.setItem('check', checkbox.checked);
}

//This function reloads the checkbox like how it was from localStorage:
window.onload = function() {    
    var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('check'));
    checkbox.checked = checked;
}

//Remember to save whenever the checkbox changes:
checkbox.addEventListener("change", save);
```

```html
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" onchange = "save();">Tick the check box</input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The other solutions to your problem (correcting `window.load`) seem good (see also the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)):
2. If you want to do JSON.parse() to restore the data, then **encoding the data in JSON** before storage seems cleaner. So you could do

   ```
   localStorage.setItem("check", JSON.stringify(checkbox.checked));
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   localStorage.setItem('check', checkbox.checked);
   ```
3. If you want persistence just for the browser session (you said "when the page is refreshed"), you can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). This is cleared after the browser ends, but is saved while the browser is active. As [localStorage apparently is loaded whenever the browser starts](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/03/there-is-no-simple-solution-for-local-storage/) (which can add up for many sites), this persists your data between reloads, but does not clutter the user's computer.